# Algorithm for polygon triangulation

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have written the following code for the generation of all "triangulations" of a regular or convex polygon:

```
def getTriangles(points,i,j):
    print('i={}, j={}'.format(i,j))
    ee = []
    if j-i<2:
        return []
    if j-i==2:
        return [[[i,i+1,j]]]
    for k in range(i+1,j):
        print('    k={}'.format(k))
        e1= getTriangles(points,i,k)
        e2 = getTriangles(points,k,j)
        for x in e1:
            for y in e2:
                e = [[i,k,j]]
                e.extend(x)
                e.extend(y)
                ee.append(e)
        if len(e1)==0:
            for y in e2:
                e = [[i,k,j]]
                e.extend(y)
                ee.append(e)
        if len(e2)==0:
            for a in e1:
                e = [[i,k,j]]
                e.extend(x)
                ee.append(e)
        print('        e1={}, e2={}, ee={}'.format(e1,e2,ee))
    return ee

n=5
tr = getTriangles(range(1,n+1),0,n-1)
print()
print(tr)
print(len(tr))
```

For n=3,4 it is correct, and in general "navigates" through the right number of possible triangulations (that is the Catalan number) for n=3,4,5,6,7,8, but the triangulations are not unique. here the formatted output for n=5, consisting of a list of triangles (e.g. three vertices in [0,1,2,3,4]):

```
[[[0, 1, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4]],
 [[0, 1, 4], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[0, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4]],
 [[0, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]], 
 [[0, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]]]
```

as you can see the last two are equal. Where is the error?
Intuitively the code is more complex than needed.

**EDIT** As you can see I'm not in bad company for this error: here is Robert Sedgewick, a computer science professor at Princeton University and in the background you see that the n=5 is correct but for n=6 there are double ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more Pythonic version of the above:

```
def genTriangles(i, j):
    if j - i < 2:
        yield []
        return
    
    if j - i == 2:
        yield [(i, i+1, j)]
        return 
    
    for k in range(i + 1, j):
        for x in genTriangles(i, k):
            for y in genTriangles(k, j):
                yield x + y + [(i, k, j)]

n = 5
for k, tr in enumerate(genTriangles(0, n - 1), 1):
    print(k, tr)

1 [(2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4), (0, 1, 4)]
2 [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 4), (0, 1, 4)]
3 [(0, 1, 2), (2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 4)]
4 [(1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3), (0, 3, 4)]
5 [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code seams to work. The change is in the middle. The algorithm fix the edge [i,j] and k moves from i+1 to j-1. The triangle ijk is fixed and split the polygon in three sub-polygons: itself, the polygon i...k, and the polygon, k..j. If k=i+1 or k=j-1, one of the two polygon is degenerate (empty):

```
def getTriangles(points,i,j):
    print('i={}, j={}'.format(i,j))
    ee = []
    if j-i<2:
        return []
    if j-i==2:
        return [[[i,i+1,j]]]
    for k in range(i+1,j): # k is the vertex such that the triangle ikj split the polygon 1j in 2 subspace plus the triangle ikj
        print('    k={}'.format(k))
        e1= getTriangles(points,i,k)
        e2 = getTriangles(points,k,j)
        if k==i+1:
            for y in e2:
                e = [[i,k,j]]
                e.extend(y)
                ee.append(e)
        elif k==j-+1:
            for x in e1:
                e = [[i,k,j]]
                e.extend(x)
                ee.append(e)
        else:
            for x in e1:
                for y in e2:
                    e = [[i,k,j]]
                    e.extend(x)
                    e.extend(y)
                    ee.append(e)
        print('        e1={}, e2={}, ee={}'.format(e1,e2,ee))
    return ee

n=5
tr = getTriangles(range(1,n+1),0,n-1)
print()
print(tr)
print(len(tr))
```